# AJAX: can't call function on image click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem with passing data with `POST` method in Ajax.

Ajax method :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#vote").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async: false, 
        url: "http://localhost/PSI/Dokumentacija/Faza5/Implementacija/votes/voteAlg", 
        data: {
            incdec: $("#vote").val(),
            alg: $("#algcode").val(),
        },
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        success: function(mess) {
            console.log(mess);
            if(mess=='voted') {
                alert("Glasali ste vec!");
            } else if (mess=='error') {
                alert("Problem sa bazom");
            } else {
                $("#algRate").val(mess);
            } 
        }
    });

    return false;
   });
 });
```

Function in controllers :

```
public function voteAlg() {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->model('vote');
        $this->vote->voteAlgDb();
    } 
    else {
        redirect('error_404');
    }

}
```

In model :

```
public function voteAlgDb() {
    $id = $this->input->post('alg');
    $incdec = $this->input->post('incdec');
    $idUser = $this->session->userdata('idUser');
    if($incdec=='inc') {
        $broj = 1;
        $this->insertVote($broj, $idAlgorithm, $idUser);
    } else if ($incdec = 'dec') {
        $broj = -1;
        $this->insertVote($broj, $idAlgorithm, $idUser);
    }

    echo $this->showNumberOfVotes($idAlgorithm);
}
```

I get this error: http://postimg.org/image/wy3vgbcu7/

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

EDIT:

Similar ajax function I used before, and everything is working well.

Comment: The problem is on the server-side. The console output indicates that the request was sent and the server had a problem while processing it.

Comment: Says it right there, CORS issue - try removing the `http://localhost` from the call.

Comment: error coming in action while processing it

Comment: Nothing happens when I remove the http://localhost